# Initialize vector passed by reference

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I have a class `Pixel` and a class `Image` with a function used to update a pixel line. I want to initialize the pixel line. My problem is to initialize the vector. Actually I have this :

```
bool UpdateLine(std::vector<Pixel>& line, int nb)
{
    bool noError = true;
    line = new std::vector<Pixel>(nb);
    // Do some stuff
    return noError;
}
```

When I try this I have :

> no viable overloaded '='

How can I initialize the vector ?

Comment: This isn't Java or C#.  `line.resize(nb);`

Comment: in your code, you are not *initializing* the vector, but *assigning* to it.

Comment: @NtFreX What makes you think so?

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the language first. I recommend reading at least one or two [books about C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @tobi303 everything *is* initialized, possibly to indeterminate values for default-initialized built-in types.

Comment: @Quentin right, removed the misleading comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you are using:

```
new std::vector<Pixel>(nb)
```

returns a pointer to `std::vector<Pixel>` (i.e.: `std::vector<Pixel> *`), and not a `std::vector<Pixel>`, which is what you need.

---

A distinction between *initialization* and *assignment* has to be done: you are *assigning* to `line` and not *initializing* it.

You can create a new vector and *assign* it to `line` by means of an *assignment operator*:

```
line = std::vector<Pixel>(nb);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take my book again, I probably misunderstood

Answer (score 1):

What you do is assignment, not initialization.

Initializing a vector could be done like this:

```
std::vector<int> second (4,100); // four ints with value 100
```

In your case however, the vector is already declared outside of the function, so in that case you use [`vector::resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) and do this:

```
line.resize(nb); // creates 'nb' objects 'Pixel'
```

PS: You don't need `new` keyword, except if you dynamically allocating memory for your vector.